# Difference of infima exceeds infima of difference

Tags: general-topology, analysis

In a project I am working on I encountered the following statement.

---

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $f,g:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ two upper semicontinuous functions. Then
$$
\inf_{x\in X}\{f(x)\} - \inf_{x\in X}\{g(x)\} \ge \inf_{x\in X}\left\{f(x)-g(x)\right\}.
$$

---

The functions in the paper have some extra properties, but these are not mentioned around the statement. However, I am sceptical of the validness of this claim based on just compactness and upper semicontinuity. On the other hand, I cannot find a counterexample. Does someone perhaps see a counterexample, or might it even be true?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Simple counterxample: let $f$ and $g$ be constant. The inequality is non-strict. But then it's true.

Comment: Thank you, it is a strict inequality in the paper, but I edited it here anyway. Could you perhaps provide a hint concerning the proof, or do you know of some text that contains it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the non-strict inequality, let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence such that $f(x_n) \to \inf\limits_{x\in X} f(x)$. Then

$$\begin{align}
\inf_{x\in X} g(x) &\leqslant \liminf_{n\to\infty} g(x_n)\\
&= \liminf_{n\to\infty} \Bigl(f(x_n) - \bigl(f(x_n) - g(x_n)\bigr)\Bigr)\\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n) - \limsup_{n\to\infty} \bigl(f(x_n) - g(x_n)\bigr)\\
&= \inf_{x\in X} f(x) - \limsup_{n\to\infty} \bigl(f(x_n) - g(x_n)\bigr),
\end{align}$$

and rearranging yields

$$\inf_{x\in X} \bigl(f(x)-g(x)\bigr) \leqslant \limsup_{n\to\infty} \bigl(f(x_n) - g(x_n)\bigr) \leqslant \inf_{x\in X} f(x) - \inf_{x\in X} g(x),$$

under the condition that $\inf\limits_{x\in X} f(x) > -\infty$. If $\inf\limits_{x\in X} f(x) = -\infty = \inf\limits_{x\in X} g(x)$, then the left hand side of the inequality is an indeterminate form and the inequality makes no sense anyway, and if $\inf\limits_{x\in X} f(x) = -\infty < \inf\limits_{x\in X} g(x)$, then $\inf_{x\in X} \bigl(f(x) - g(x)\bigr) = -\infty = \inf\limits_{x\in X} f(x) - \inf\limits_{x\in X} g(x)$.

Note that neither compactness nor semicontinuity is needed.